# How to filter in django by id of foriegn key

Tags: python, django

i want to filter by id of Foreign key in django.
 my model.py

```
class CustomerLeads(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    event = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    item_required = models.ForeignKey(ProductClass,null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

i want to search by item_required.
i am getting ids for ProductClass values like 12,13.,
as id is default in django.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter using the `id` as below:

```
CustomerLeads.objects.filter(item_required__pk=12)
```

OR you can filter using the `ProductClass` object after retrieving it:

```
pc = ProductClass.objects.get(pk=12)
CustomerLeads.objects.filter(item_required=pc)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways to do this, depending on what you are trying to do in the end:

1. Get all `CustomerLeads` for a specific set of `ProductClass` items:

   ```
   CustomerLeads.objects.filter(item_required__pk__in=[12,13,14])
   ```
2. For a given `ProductClass`, get all of its `CustomerLeads`':

   ```
   p = ProductClass.objects.get(pk=12)
   customer_leads = p.customerleads_set.all()
   ```